# MongoDB (Java driver) - Query date in interval

Tags: java, jquery, mongodb, date, driver

I'm new to MongoDB and trying to make a query with the Java driver to get some records within a date interval.

In the shell when I do this :

```
db.messages.find({
    "date" : {
        $gt: ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:05Z")
    }
});
```

It returns 4 records.

In Java I'm doing this:

```
try {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1 = dateFormat.parse("2014-01-01 00:00:00");
    Date d2 = dateFormat.parse("2014-01-01 00:00:05");

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.append("date", new BasicDBObject().append("$gte", d1).append("$lt", d2));

    System.out.println(query);
}
catch (ParseException ex) { Logger.getLogger(MongoDbNavigationMessageDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); }
```

If I search the query, I get no record. Moreover, the output of System.out.println(query); is :

```
{ "date" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2013-12-31T23:00:00.000Z"} , "$lt" : { "$date" : "2013-12-31T23:00:05.000Z"}}}
```

As you can see, the dates are wrong... What's going on??

Answer (score 0):

Well I found it, the printed date isn't the same because MongoDB is taking the timezone into account. And I had no result because of a typo...